# To what types do the references get assigned instead of being copied in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, memory, pointers, garbage-collection

I am on my mobile phone, so I can't test for myself. Also, I might miss something.

I know that when a number is being assigned, say a = b, b is actually copied into a. But, if b was an object, just a reference wouls be passed. What with other types? Is there something I should worry about?

Also, I heard that you can't use pointers in C# because variables get moved around by the JC. Is it the same in Javascript? How are these references solved in these languages then?

Comment: Primitives are copied, all other object values are passed by reference.

Comment: also, Javascript has 5 primitive types: number, string, boolean, undefined, and null. Everything else is an object.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - Done an `alert(typeof null)` lately? Bane - JS doesn't have pointers: references and pointers are kind of overlapping concepts but they're not the same thing. Also note that "pass by reference" has a specific meaning in some languages for function parameters where the function can assign a new reference to the variable outside the function that was passed as a parameter but that is not the case with JavaScript.

Comment: @nnnnnn The `typeof` operator has a well-known bug in this regard. They [wanted to fix it](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null) for Ecmascript harmony, but then they found that that would break too many scripts. So we're gonna have to live with the fact that `typeof null == 'object'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**javascript**
According to specification, you have types: undefined, null, boolean, string, number, object. You can think of them as *immutable* except object, which is practically just a (hash)map.
So yes, if you assign variable, it's "copied" (you don't care if it really is) unless it's an object type. Take example:

```
var x = "hello";
var y = x; //copy or reference, who cares?
x += " world"; //new string object, x references it
alert(y); //alerts hello
```

**C#**
According to C# 2.0 specification, there are **struct/value types** and **class/reference types**. So, from practical point of view, variable of value type actually stores the data on the call stack (and gets copied on assignment), and variable of reference types is just a reference (and data goes to heap). Example:

```
int holds_a_value = 5;
StringBuilder holds_a_reference = new StringBuilder();
```

You can use **pointers** in C# (pointer = reference), but you have to **pin** them if you call unsafe functions **outside .net / C#**, or using **unsafe** code. e.g.:

```
fixed (int* p = something) { /*p is safe to use, memory doesn't move */}
```

Comment: It is not necessary that non-objects are copied - as you say, they are immutable and so you can't make out a difference (in Python and Ruby, you can because you can look at object identity). I find the model of "everything is referred to by indirection and hence nothing but references is copied" conceptually simpler.